# Finding whether a string is a substring of another with Miller/mlr's DSL

Tags: miller

How do I find whether a column of a CSV contains another using mlr's DSL?

In other words I have a CSV

```
a,b
test and,test and more
```

and want to find out whether `'test and'` (a) is included in `'test and more'` (b)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note**: I have edited my reply, using the great comment of [@Kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/731761/finding-whether-a-string-is-a-substring-of-another-with-miller-mlrs-dsl/731765?noredirect=1#comment1388529_731765)

---

If you have

```
a,b
test*and,test*and more
lorem,ipsum
whether,Finding whether a string
```

you can run

```
mlr --csv put 'if($b != ssub($b,$a,"")){$test=1}else{$test=0}' input.csv
```

to get

| a | b | test |
| --- | --- | --- |
| test*and | test*and more | 1 |
| lorem | ipsum | 0 |
| whether | Finding whether a string | 1 |

I'm using the [`ssub`](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference-dsl-builtin-functions/index.html#ssub) function, to check if I have or not a string replace in `b` - no regexing, no characters are special - using strings I have in `a`.

`if($b != ssub($b,$a,""))`, if after string replace `b` is not equal to itself, then `a` is contained in `b`.

If you want simply to filter, you can run

```
mlr --csv filter '$b != ssub($b,$a,"")' input.csv
```

to get

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| test*and | test*and more |
| whether | Finding whether a string |

Thank you [@Kusalananda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/116858/kusalananda)

Comment: I found the cause, but not the solution

Having an asterix '*' in a field messes up the regex. Any ideas for that?

Comment: I do not understand. Do it solve exactly your example? If no, could you explain why not?

Comment: Could you add it in your example in the question?

Comment: The issue is that `$a` must be interpreted as a string, not as a regular expression.  For example, `.*` is included in the string `It matches ".*"`, but not in `It does not match`.

Comment: @ELisse I have edited my reply

Comment: @aborruso You have now made a workaround for a specific case of regular expression, but not for others. It would be better to avoid using `$a` as a regular expression _at all_, as in `if ($b == ssub($b,$a,""))`. Also consider using `filter` insteadof `put` as the question requires filtering records, not adding or modifying fields: `mlr --csv filter '$b != ssub($b,$a,"")'`

Comment: @Kusalananda as usual, you are great. I add it in my reply, but I have no merit

Comment: @ELisse please try the new way, and let us know

Comment: Brilliant! I can't use the `filter` solution in my particular case as I need concatenate `$a . " " . $b . " " . $c` with an eventual `clean-whitespace`. Unless you can propose something equally elegant, of course :-)-O

Comment: @ELisse If you want to clarify your question (by adding restrictions or further information about your the way you need to handle your data), please do so by editing the question. This answer resolves your query exactly  as it is currently posed.